# How to handle Google translating source strings that contain formatting replacement variables.

Tags: google-translate

I have a English source string with some formatting. For example:

```
The chance of success is %d%%.
```

But when I google translate it into Japanese, it mangles the formatting.

```
成功のチャンスは％dの%%です。
```

I'm looking for a method to protect the format string through the translation process.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the variable to an HTML tag temporarily. Google parses HTML pretty well.

For example:

```
The chance of success is <var></var>.
```

Would return:

```
成功のチャンスは<VAR></VAR>である。
```

You can then convert it back to the original variable form.

Comment: Seems like bad practice because not all HTML is parsed correctly in all languages. For example, `<footer>` gets translated entirely in Japanese, which is why people usually do things like `<0footer>` when trying to translate HTML. Seems like you're taking a chance that "var" won't be translated in some language. Also in your case var translates to uppercase. Just seems better to use a numeric identifier in most situations. :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around for this problem by replacing the format string with a unique number.

```
The chance of success is 100.
```

Which in Japanese translates to this:

```
成功のチャンスは100です。
```

And then I can replace the unique number back with my format:

```
成功のチャンスは%d%%です。
```

This seemed to work well with several languages. I chose a number below 1000 because some translated languages will add formatting to the unique number.